# Moving from WebSphere to Oracle WebLogic, getting a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: weblogic, springframework

I was given an "EAR" file and told to try to deploy it on an Oracle WebLogic server.  I had successfully deployed it on a IBM WebSphere server.  When I attempt to start it on WebLogic, however, I get the following error:

> Could not load user defined listener:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
>   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:37)
>   at

I've checked that spring.war is in WEB-INF/lib in the appropriate war files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to load libs from your WEB-INF/lib directory then you need to add something to your `weblogic.xml` file (this should be in WEB-INF).

```
<weblogic-web-app>
   <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
   </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Hope that helps.